# Транспонирование таблицы (строки в столбцы)

Tags: sql

Какой запрос может транспонировать таблицу (строки станут столбцами)?

Причем, без использования функции `pivot`.

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: MySQL
но на самом деле это неважно
надо просто сделать задачку с небольшой таблицей

Comment: Допустим есть таблица 3*3
Ее надо транспонировать без использования pivot с помощью агрегатных функций и группировки

Comment: https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/

Comment: Да без проблем в ручную делайте. Вам известна таблица и как она должна выглядеть. Делайте какие проблемы

Comment: Заголовок хардкод. Каждая ячейка отдельный запрос. И объединение записей через union all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычный запрос, это просто.

Было:

```
select * from t1
/

NAME      VALUE
---- ----------
Вася        427
Петя        379
Маша        254
Паша        881
Коля        481
```

Стало:

```
select
    sum (case name when 'Вася' then value end) "Вася",
    sum (case name when 'Петя' then value end) "Петя",
    sum (case name when 'Маша' then value end) "Маша",
    sum (case name when 'Паша' then value end) "Паша",
    sum (case name when 'Коля' then value end) "Коля"
from t1
/

      Вася       Петя       Маша       Паша       Коля
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       427        379        254        881        481
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про Pivot. Но и это не полное транспонирование в понимании матриц. Так как таблица в базе данных это не матрица.

На выборку типа

```
  SELECT DaysToManufacture, 
          AVG(StandardCost) AS AverageCost   
  FROM Production.Product  
  GROUP BY DaysToManufacture;  

DaysToManufacture AverageCost
----------------- -----------
0                 5.0885
1                 223.88
2                 359.1082
4                 949.4105
```

Применив pivot

```
  SELECT 'AverageCost' AS 
          Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days,   
          [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]  
  FROM  
      (SELECT DaysToManufacture, 
              StandardCost   
       FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable  
  PIVOT  
  (  
    AVG(StandardCost)  
    FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])  
  ) AS PivotTable;
```

Мы получим

```
Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days 0           1           2           3           4         
------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
AverageCost                    5.0885      223.88      359.1082    NULL        949.4105
```

Comment: А без использования pivot

Comment: Понимаете вы пытаетесь заменить поля записями. Можете в ручную повернуть таблицу но имейте ввиду что создать 1 000 000 колонок не получится а записей легко

Comment: Я вам говорю что таблица в базе данных это не матрица

Comment: И сделать по типу a[i,j] = a[j,i] не получится